# How change MariaDB config?

Tags: mysql, server, mariadb, my.cnf

i want to change MariaDB config but there is no my.cnf in /etc/ and there is no Mysql folder in /etc

before this i removed MariaDB and install a fresh MariaDB server 5.5.63 but after install it, can not find My.cnf

so i created my.cnf in /etc but MariaDB can not restart.

in /etc just there is a folder that named /My.cnf.d and 3 file : Server.cnf , Mariadb-client.cnf and tokudb.cnf

How i can change config?

Comment: Which was the previous MariaDB version? What was the error in the mysql error log? What OS/distro are you using?

Comment: i think the previous version was 5.5.59. mysql log is empty. OS is centos 7

Comment: you might have installed mariadb but not mariadb-server. How did you try to start?

Comment: no ,it was installed.( yum install mariadb mariadb-server)

Comment: Show us your my.cnf; we might spot a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one on your linux console:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

If you would like to make your MariaDB accessible from outside ( not standard) then you have to change the line:

```
bind-address                              = 127.0.0.1
```

To

```
bind-address                               = 0.0.0.0
```